# Print rows of df as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
category    ID  values
       A   foo  ABCDEF
       A   baz  GHIJKL
       B   bar  MNOPQR
       B  biff  STUVWX
       C   bop  YZABCD
```

All of the `values` are the same length.

I'd like to print the `ID` and `values` columns into a csv file, but printing the `values` as columns, so the file would like this:

```
foo  bar  baz  biff  bop
A    G    M    S     Y
B    H    N    T     Z
C    I    O    U     A
D    J    P    V     B
E    K    Q    W     C
F    L    R    X     D
```

The only method I can see is to create a numpy array with the correct lengths, fill it iteratively with the `values` column, then turn that into a df and use pandas print to csv method, with `ID` as the header. I know how to do that, but it just seems terribly inefficient.

Does anyone have a better / faster method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and the DataFrame constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['values']), columns=df['ID'])
```

Output:

```
ID foo baz bar biff bop
0    A   G   M    S   Y
1    B   H   N    T   Z
2    C   I   O    U   A
3    D   J   P    V   B
4    E   K   Q    W   C
5    F   L   R    X   D
```

##### timing of the (functional) solutions

```
%%timeit
out = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['values']), columns=df['ID'])
# 258 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = pd.DataFrame({i: [*v] for i, v in zip(df['ID'], df['values'])})
# 279 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].apply(list).tolist()).T
out.columns = df['ID']
# 585 µs ± 58.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
out = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('ID')['values'].apply(list).to_dict())
# 819 µs ± 41.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit 
out = df.set_index('ID')['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).T
# 1.48 ms ± 86.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

```
>>> df.set_index('ID')['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).T

# OR

>>> pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('ID')['values'].apply(list).to_dict())

ID foo baz bar biff bop
0    A   G   M    S   Y
1    B   H   N    T   Z
2    C   I   O    U   A
3    D   J   P    V   B
4    E   K   Q    W   C
5    F   L   R    X   D
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets use dict comprehension to create a mapping of ID -> values

```
pd.DataFrame({i: [*v] for i, v in zip(df['ID'], df['values'])})
```

---

```
  foo baz bar biff bop
0   A   G   M    S   Y
1   B   H   N    T   Z
2   C   I   O    U   A
3   D   J   P    V   B
4   E   K   Q    W   C
5   F   L   R    X   D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].apply(list).tolist()).T
out.columns = df['ID']
print(out)

ID foo baz bar biff bop
0    A   G   M    S   Y
1    B   H   N    T   Z
2    C   I   O    U   A
3    D   J   P    V   B
4    E   K   Q    W   C
5    F   L   R    X   D
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use pandas transpose**

```
df2=df.set_index('ID')
print(df2.T)

# OR

print(df2.transpose())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([list(i) for i in df['values']]).T, columns=df['ID'])
```

Output:

```
ID foo baz bar biff bop
0    A   G   M    S   Y
1    B   H   N    T   Z
2    C   I   O    U   A
3    D   J   P    V   B
4    E   K   Q    W   C
5    F   L   R    X   D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df11=df1.assign(category=0).pivot("category","ID","values").applymap(list)
df11.explode(df11.columns.tolist())
```

out

```
ID       bar baz biff bop foo
category                     
0          M   G    S   Y   A
0          N   H    T   Z   B
0          O   I    U   A   C
0          P   J    V   B   D
0          Q   K    W   C   E
0          R   L    X   D   F
```